# How to keV^{inverse} in SI?

Tags: siunitx

I would like to have `$keV^{-1}$` in SI package. 
My unsuccessful attempt:

```
\SI{}{ke \per \volt}
```

giving

[image]

How can you write keV to inverse in SI package?

Comment: `\si[per-mode=symbol]{\per\kilo\eV}`?

Comment: @HenriMenke Drop the `per-mode = symbol` and you have the answer ;-)

Comment: @JosephWright I guess the slash is intended, according to the picture in the question.  On the other hand, the textual mockup suggests your choice.

Comment: @HenriMenke The unit is “electronvolt” (eV), so “kiloelectronvolt” is the only thing that makes sense and the exponent refers to the whole thing.

Comment: Just `\si{keV^{-1}}` ?

Comment: Normall y this should be the default. Maybe some package changes this default. Try `\sisetup{per-mode=reciprocal}`.

Comment: @egreg The usage of the slash seems to be intended.  The placement is obviously wrong and correct in my very first comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Henri Menke's comment with little edit by Joseph Wright:

```
\si{\per\kilo\eV}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
\SI{}{\per\kilo\electronvolt}
```

or

```
\SI{}{\per\keV}
```

Comment: Was just about to do that Romain Picot, my bad